# UITableView drag button pressed in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to do a draggable UITableView (this part is working), but when I long press on one row I want to show boxes to change cell's content.

The problem is that long press in editing mode is fired when I am pressing drag or delete button, causing drag event to be stopped. I can't use `[[self tableView] isDragging]` to ignore long press when I am dragging because it only returns true when I have already dragged far enough.

To summarise I need:

- Drag event not to be stopped when long press is fired.
- Ignore long press inside drag or delete buttons.

Any ideas?